# $\mathbb{Z}_2(u)$ is a field of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Find an irreducible polynomial $f$ with degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Assign a root $u$ of $f$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to get the field $\mathbb{Z}_2 (u)$ of order 4. Use the same method to construct a field of order 8.

My attempt:

$f$ is reducible if and only if $f=gh$ with $g,h$ non constant polynomial. Hence $2=deg(f)=deg(h)+deg(g)$. From here we have that $1=deg(g)=deg(h)$.

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_2=\lbrace [0], [1]\rbrace$, the polynomials of degree 1 are $x,x+1$ and the polynomials of degree 2 are $x^2,x^2+1,x^2+x,x^2+x+1$. Hence, the only irreducible polynomial is $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ with roots $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

The difficulty I have is that I don't know which root to attach to $ \mathbb {Z} _2 $, how to check that the resulting field has order 4 and how to do the same to obtain a field of order 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is like "$i$ is defined to be **a root** of $x^2+1 \in \mathbb R[x]$" (which of both roots? It doesn't matter). Indeed, if $u$ is defined to be a root of $x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb Z_2[x]$, then $\mathbb Z_2(u) = \{a+bu : a,b \in \mathbb Z_2\}$ is a field with $4$ elements. Compare this with $\mathbb C = \mathbb R(i) = \{a+bi: a,b \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see...
But how can I determinete the form of $u$ as root of $f$ as element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$?@azif00

Comment: You don't need a "form of $u$", all you need is that $u$ is defined to be a root – any root – of $x^2+x+1$ over the field of two elements.

Comment: I understand. But then what is the point of finding $ f $? Because if we just use $ u $ as any root of some polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the argument still works ... or not? @GerryMyerson

Comment: @RicardoCalderón No, $u$ is not an element of $\mathbb Z_2$, in the same way that $i$ is not an element of $\mathbb R$. If you're worried about how the "Define $u$ to be a root of $f := x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb Z_2[x]$" can be formalized, this can be done with the concept of quotient ring. First, let $(f)$ be the ideal of $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ generated by $f$. Then, if $\pi : \mathbb Z_2[x] \to \mathbb Z_2[x]/(f)$ is the canonical projection, identify $\mathbb Z_2$ with $\pi(\mathbb Z_2)$, and call $u := \pi(x)$. Thus $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(f) = \{a+bu : a,b \in \mathbb Z_2\}$.

Comment: No, Ricardo, if you want a field of four elements, then only an irreducible polynomial of degree two works.

Comment: So if I'm getting it right, what I need to do now is: Find an irreducible polynomial of degree four, take some of its roots and attach it to the field. With this I will have a field of 8 elements ... right? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Wrong. Degree three.

Comment: I don't see why it must be 3 ... can you explain in a little more detail how this is reasoned? @GerryMyerson

Comment: If $u$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree three, then the elements of ${\bf Z}_2(u)$ are the objects $a+bu+cu^2$ with $a,b,c$ in ${\bf Z}_2$. There are eight such things.

Comment: This would be considering $ \mathbb{Z}_2(u) $ as $ \mathbb{Z}_2 $ -vector space, right? So a base would be $\lbrace 1, u, u^2 \rbrace$ @GerryMyerson

Comment: Yes, but it's also an extension field of ${\bf Z}_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126161/discussion-between-ricardo-calderon-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. I suggest that you must have study materials which cover the questions under discussion here, so have a look at them, or just search the web for stuff about extensions of finite fields.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve the exercise. Thanks! @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial. If $u$ is a root of $f$ we have that $\mathbb{Z}_2(u)=\lbrace a+bu : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \rbrace$.

In a similar way, we can find that the irreducible polynomials of degree 3 are $x^3+x+1$ and $x^3+x^2+1$. Then if we take $u$ as a root of any of these polynomials, we have that
$$\mathbb{Z}_2(u)= \lbrace a+bu+cu^2 : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \rbrace $$

And clearly these fields have 4 and 8 elements, resp.